# How to set up Django TabularInline so I can edit intermediate table object

Tags: django, admin

I'm using a TabularInline editor to allow editing of a model's relationship to another model.  It's a many-to-many thru a map table.  Is there a way to get django to put in an icon-link to the map table itself in the rows of the tabularInline?

For example,  If Machine and Part are mapped together by Machine2Part and I use a tabularInline within the Machine to provide editing of its Parts,  I will get pulldown menus that allow me to select Parts which is great, but I also want a link that takes me to an admin form for the Machine2Part object/row that sits behind this relationship because my Machine2Part admin form has field editing that I want to be able to access from this location.

```
class Part (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "part"

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name

class Machine (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part, through='Machine2Part')
    class Meta:
        db_table = "machine"

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name


class Machine2Part (models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine,db_column='machineId')
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part,db_column='partId')
    class Meta:
        db_table = "machine2part"

class Machine2PartInline (admin.TabularInline):
    # fields = ['name']
    model = Machine2Part

class MachineAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [Machine2PartInline]

admin.site.register(Machine, MachineAdmin)
admin.site.register(Part)
admin.site.register(Machine2Part)
```

Answer (score 0):

The show_change_link = True will add a "Change" link next to each row in the TabularInline

```
class Machine2PartInline (admin.TabularInline):
    # fields = ['name']
    model = Machine2Part
    show_change_link = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model `Machine2Part` contains additional fields (besides the FKs) you can use this to show the fields inside the inline, no need for additional link.

```
class Machine2PartInline (admin.TabularInline):
    model = Machine.parts.through
```

[See django docs reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)

Comment: Yeah,  that would be good if I wanted to see the extra fields on my intermediate table.  Unfortunately, what I want to see are some fields on other tables that are related to this intermediate Machine2Part (i.e. my intermediate table has more than just Machine and Part with foreign keys to it) so getting to the appropriate Machine2Part directly from the tabular inline is desirable.